# Prevent user from deselecting an item in a ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got a ListBox with a bunch of items in it. The user can click an item to edit its contents. How do I prevent the user from deselecting all items? i.e., the user shouldn't be able to have nothing selected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF ListBox: do not allow unselect/deselect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815844/wpf-listbox-do-not-allow-unselect-deselect)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a case missing in your situation, which is **when the list is cleared you will reselect an item there is no longer on the list**. I solve this by adding an extra check.

```
        var listbox = ((ListBox)sender);
        if (listbox.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                object itemToReselect = e.RemovedItems[0];
                if (listbox.Items.Contains(itemToReselect))
                {
                    listbox.SelectedItem = itemToReselect;
                }
            }
        }
```

I then put this [inside a behaviour](https://gist.github.com/joaoportela/9787879).

Comment: How do you attach this behavior to the ListBox in XAML?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a direct way to disable deselecting an Item, but one way which would be transparent to the user is to keep track of the last selected Item, and whenever the [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx) event is raised and the selected index is -1, then reselect the last value.

Comment: Weird... I only see a `SelectionChanged` event. It's definitely a `ListBox` though... using WPF and .net 4...

Comment: @Mark: Correct, the links amccormack posts are for winforms (Windows.Forms namespace).  The gist of the answer still applies, though.

Answer (score 1):

This Works for Sure to Prevent User from Deselect... Add those 2 Events to your checkedListBox1 and set the **Property CheckOnClick to "True"** in Design Mode. (MSVS2015)

```
        private void checkedListBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex, true);
        }

        private void checkedListBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex, true);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable on or more options in your listbox/dropdown, you can add the "disabled" attribute as shown below. This prevent the user from selection this option, and it gets a gray overlay.

```
ListItem item = new ListItem(yourvalue, yourkey);
item.Attributes.Add("disabled","disabled");
lb1.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: I think this is the opposite of what I wanted when I asked this question. I wanted to prevent users from *deselecting* an option, not selecting it. Unless you mean I could disable the last list item when they're down to 1....I'm not sure if that would give me the desired behaviour or not though.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, as suggested by `amccormack`:

```
    private void hostsListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(lstHosts.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            if(e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                lstHosts.SelectedItem = e.RemovedItems[0];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `ListView` supports `Multiple` selection, this worked for me.

```
var found = e.RemovedItems.Cast<User>()
                          .Where(user => user.Id == Id);
if (found.Any())
{
    User user = found.First();
    user.Selected = true;
    (e.Source as ListView).SelectedItems.Add(user);
}
```

This solution should work regardless of `Single` or `Multiple` `SelectionMode`. If you have multiple items that you want them to be kept selected, adjust the code accordingly by adding your object back into `SelectedItems` property.