# C# ListBox Selection Unchanged Event?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015, listbox

I want to be able to de-select an item in the `ListBox` if the user clicks the same item again. There is the `SelectionChanged` event that everyone uses with `ListBoxes`, but this obviously will not fire when the selection is unchanged.

There is also no `Click` event, something people recommend. Visual Studio C# 2015 does not contain such event.

[image]

I have tried using `MouseLeftButtonDown` event, but once the `ListBox` has been populated with `ListBoxItems`, this event does not fire anymore. In addition, I thought about attaching Mouse events to the `ListBoxItems`, but this does not seem practicable, as I would have to attach `n` number of new events every time I populate the `ListBox`.

Does anyone have a XAML solution to this inquiry?

Comment: Setting `SelectionMode="Multiple"` enables to selected multiple items, but also to select and deselect items with a single mouse click.

Comment: @Clemens the user should not be able to select multiple items, but I appreciate the answer. mm8's answer works as I had wanted.

Comment: Just in case you don't know that already, `Ctrl+Click` deselects the selected item in single selection mode (and also in extended mode). That's probably also what users of your application may expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally selected **mm8**'s answer, but I later learned that `SelectedIndex` is not updated during the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event, a feature I indirectly was asking for in the question. You actually get the previous, out-of-date `SelectedIndex` value when using this event.

I found out if you use the `MouseLeftButtonUp` event, it actually fires, unlike the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event, and I get the most recent value for the `SelectedIndex` variable.

For anyone that cares, this is the `System.Windows.Controls`'s `ListBox` version. I tried using the `Systems.Windows.Forms`'s `ListBox` implementation, but it does not support multi-lines out of the box, unlike `Controls`, so I threw away that idea.

**tldr**

Use `MouseLeftButtonUp` event.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event for the `ListBox` container as I suggested here.

[How to disable deselection of items in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526965/how-to-disable-deselection-of-items-in-listview/41535668#41535668)

Comment: It looks like `SelectedIndex` is updated after the call to this event function. Is there anyway to get the currently selected item index from within this function?