# Button.IsSelected type of Property in WPF MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, button, menu

I have few buttons as Menu in my WPF App.

This scenario is something like menu in a website.

When I click one of the button, I want that button style to be different from others, and when I select another, the previous one should be normal and a selectedstyle should apply on this selected button.

Can you tell me how can I achieve this through ControlTemplate or do I have to maintain a IsSelected property that let us know which button is selected?

Thanks,

VJ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with the RadionButton. The below sample will create a Flat button look for the RadioButton.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="472">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
        <Setter Property="Focusable"
                Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="GroupName"
                Value="filter" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
                Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>

                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                                    Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                                    Value="Center" />
                        </Style>

                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Border x:Name="PART_border"
                            CornerRadius="2"
                            Margin="2"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            BorderBrush="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrush}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_content" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                                 Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_content"
                                    Property="TextBlock.FontWeight"
                                    Value="Bold" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_border"
                                    Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                                         EndPoint="0,1">
                                        <GradientStop Color="Black"
                                                      Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="white"
                                                      Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <RadioButton Height="30" Width="100" Content="First"></RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Height="30"
                 Width="100"
                 Content="Second"></RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Height="30"
                 Width="100"
                 Content="First"></RadioButton>
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

for RadioButton with Image just have look at Matt's blog

http://madprops.org/blog/wpf-killed-the-radiobutton-star/

Answer (score 1):

You should use the built in visual state handling and create the states / styles in XAML.

In your concrete case it seems that what you're after is a group of RadioButtons, so that you don't have to write any code to deal with switching between states.

Comment: How can we style a radio button into a button?

Comment: How about using a ToggleButton. Can I achieve the same from this?

Comment: Do you have Expression Blend? It's the easiest to do this with Blend, where you can add a RadioButton > Right click > Edit Template > Edit a copy..., which will generate the default control template for you, ready to be customised to look like a Button (or even a ToggleButton)

Comment: Yeah, you can use ToggleButtons, but then you have to do a bit of manual wiring to make the previous one "untoggle" itself when you press the next one, using RadioButtons and grouping them would mean that this is taken care of.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is also an answer. But can only mark 1 answer.

Comment: No worries, Kishore's answer is more useful with the actual XAML snippet :)

Answer (score 0):

You better Use a Custom RadioButton List for this purpose.Check out the below post.

[Do not allow unselect/deselect in ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815844/wpf-listbox-do-not-allow-unselect-deselect/5818258#5818258)

You can easily customize the selected and deselected styles to match your requirement